# whatsapp://send?text cut string from '&' character till end?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href, whatsapp

I'm trying to add a link that can be shared in WhatsApp:

For example:

```
"whatsapp://send?text=http://www.example.com/products/women/dresses?sessionid=34567&source=google.com"
```

But the link that is sent in WhatsApp is truncated from the '&' until the end. (the second parameter)

The same thing happens when I try:

```
"WhatsApp://send?text=http://www.example.com/prod&ucts/"
```

(note the '&' in the middle of the word 'prod&ucts')
The text after the '&' is truncated.

Any suggestions why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

It'll be cutting it off because an '&' denotes a new query string parameter.  You can fix it by encoding the string parameter in your URL using the `encodeURI` JavaScript function.  The & character will encode to "%26".

Comment: 'encodeURI' not work, but 'encodeURIComponent' solved the issue.

Comment: 'encodeURIComponent' Worked for me. Thanks!