# Whatsapp only sharing first parameter of window.location.search

Tags: javascript, whatsapp, sharing, window.location

I have a whatsapp share button that shares the current URL (using window.location)

```
waCurrentPage = function() {
return encodeURI("whatsapp://send?text=Lets go here: " + 'http://' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
}
```

Button

```
<a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-whatsapp" href="javascript:window.location=waCurrentPage();">Whatsapp share this list</a>
```

I can see that from the browser side it's sending the correct URL...

[image]

...but when it gets to the whatsapp side it has cut off the second parameter

[image]

Anyone have an idea how I could fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [whatsapp://send?text cut string from '&' character till end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318772/whatsapp-sendtext-cut-string-from-character-till-end)

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely closer. That just adds the whatsapp URL to the end of my domain URL and tries to refresh the page, meaning I get a 404 error.

Comment: Only use the encodeURIComponent on the part from "Lets..."  to the end, so that you don't double encode the `whatsapp://`